# mysql join 2 tables with on condition , keep some values

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables.

`users(id,username)` and `links(id,usernameORid)`.

**Example of rows:** `users{ [1,test] , [2,stack] }` and `links{ [1,overflow] , [2, 1] }`

So, table `links` may contain username or id from table `users`. As you can see in the example,
`usernameORid` from `links` may not contain the `id` or `username` from users. 
I hope you understood my example.

**Now, i have this query:**

```
SELECT  l.usernameORid, u.username, u.id
FROM links l
LEFT JOIN users u 
    ON l.usernameORid= u.id
LEFT JOIN user_roles ur
    ON ur.userID = u.id
WHERE ur.roleID < 4
group by u.id
```

But this query does not return rows from `links` if `usernameORid` is not an actual `username` or `id` from `users`.

In the previous example, will not return row `[1,overflow]`. I want that row too.

How can i achieve that?

***EDIT:*** The problem is partialy related to

```
LEFT JOIN user_roles ur
ON ur.userID = u.id
WHERE ur.roleID < 4
```

but still, how can i achieve that?

`user_roles ( id,userID,roleID)`

Comment: What is the role of `userID = 1`? If it's not less than 4, it won't be included.

Comment: Since `usernameORid` does not exist in `users`, then it will not be in `user_roles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your final `WHERE` condition to:

```
WHERE ur.roleID < 4 OR u.id IS NULL
```

This will allow it to return rows that didn't have a match in `users`. Normally a `LEFT JOIN` does that by itself, but since you're doing an additional join on that table, the `WHERE` clause is filtering those non-matching rows out because they don't have a `roleID`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OR statement in your join between `links` and `users`. This will allow you to pick up `users` records where the `link.usernameORid` is equal to either the `users.id` or the `users.username`

```
SELECT l.usernameORid,
    u.username,
    u.id
FROM links l
LEFT JOIN users u ON 
    l.usernameORid = u.id OR
    lusernameORid = u.username
LEFT JOIN user_roles ur
    ON ur.userID = u.id
WHERE ur.roleID < 4
GROUP BY u.id
```

This will still cause records to drop if the found `users->user_roles.roleID` is less than 4. If you wanted to have link records maintained regardless of whether of a user was found by username or ID then you would need to subquery the `users` and `user_roles` table joins and apply your `WHERE` statement there instead. This query is below:

```
SELECT  
     l.usernameORid,
     u.username,
     u.id
FROM links l
LEFT JOIN 
    (   
        SELECT
            users.username,
            users.idusers
        FROM
            users
            LEFT JOIN user_roles ON
                user_roles.userID = users.id
        WHERE 
            user_roles.roleID < 4
    ) u ON
        l.usernameORid= u.id OR
        l.usernameORid = u.username
group by u.id
```

Furthermore, if you wish the 2nd or 3rd column of your return to hold the value that is in l.usernameORid when the `users` table lacks a match... if your `users.id` is always numeric you could do some trickery with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT  
    l.usernameORid,
    Coalesce(u.username, CASE WHEN .lusernameORid REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN NULL ELSE l.usernameORid END) as username,
    Coalesce(u.username, CASE WHEN .lusernameORid REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN l.usernameORid ELSE NULL END) as userid
FROM links l
LEFT JOIN 
    (   
        SELECT
            users.username,
            users.idusers
        FROM
            users
            LEFT JOIN user_roles ON
                user_roles.userID = users.id
        WHERE 
            user_roles.roleID < 4
    ) u ON
        l.usernameORid= u.id OR
        l.usernameORid = u.username
group by u.id
```

Keep in mind though, that if the `users` table doesn't have a match for the `links.usernameORid` then only the username OR the id could be determined, so you will have a NULL in one of the two fields.

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the problem, since there's no row in `users` with `username = "overflow"`.

Comment: I have added the extra logic in to perform the subquery. You will only have l.usernameORid filled in when there is no matching user in the user table though. `u.username` and `u.id` will be null.

Comment: Edited again to add a third statement that will populate the 2nd or 3rd field returned by the query depending on whether the l.usernameORid field is a username or an id.